# android schedule task to execute at specific time daily

Tags: android

I am wanting to change my ringtone volume at specific time each day. I used a calendar to specify the time, and I am attempting to use alarmManager to execute it but it won't set the volume to vibrate at the time I specified. Here is what I have. (I am a noobie go easy on me).

```
package com.example.ringervolume.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Calendar;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


    private AudioManager audio;
    private PendingIntent pendingIntentam;
    private PendingIntent pentdingIntentpm;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView textViewTime = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textTime);
        audio = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        //ringer volume for the am.
        Calendar calendaram = Calendar.getInstance();

        calendaram.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 21);
        calendaram.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 32);
        calendaram.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendaram.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.PM);



        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyReceiver.class);
        pendingIntentam = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0,myIntent,0);
        AlarmManager alarmManageram = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManageram.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendaram.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntentam);


    }

    public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Intent scheduledIntent = new Intent(context, myscheduleactivity.class);
            scheduledIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(scheduledIntent);

        }
    }

    public class myscheduleactivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            audio.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
        }
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code?

Comment: I forgot to add it, basically it wont set the volume to vibrate at the time I specified.

Comment: You have another activity as a inner class of the current activity. Move it to a separate `.java` file. Also see if you have registered the broadcastreceiver.

Comment: Please check out
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35703898/schedule-a-timertask-at-specific-time-once-per-day-in-a-service-in-android

Answer (score 24):

To fire alarm everyday, at 21:32

```
private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
private PendingIntent alarmIntent;
...
alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

// Set the alarm to start at 21:32 PM
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 21);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 32);

// setRepeating() lets you specify a precise custom interval--in this case,
// 1 day
alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
```

In this case, `AlarmReceiver` is the Broadcast Receiver and it already has a context, so you can directly set the ringer mode to silent from the Broadcast Receiver without starting an activity.

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);   
       am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
}
```

Please be sure to add these permissions :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" ></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION" ></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" ></uses-permission>
```

Comment: thank you for the response, the line that is containing Intent intent, it says cannot resolve symbole 'context' any idea what they mean?

Comment: use MainReceiver.this in place of the context variable.

Comment: Thank you, I gave it another shot but it seems to be not working, I have been trying to understand logcat to make sense why its not working.

Comment: will the daily alarm be called even if the app is killed?

Comment: This is an old answer, but just note that this solution requires permissions for Android >=6.0

Answer (score 11):

If Shivam Verma's answer does not work for you, make sure you add the receiver to your manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".receivers.MyReceiver" />
```

Comment: add this code if your `AlarmReceiver` is a `BroadcastReceiver`. Otherwise, there is no point.