# Android set repeating task at same time everyday using AlarmManager

Tags: android, scheduled-tasks, android-alarms

Have to schedule an event at 8 pm (the clock shows 8 pm) everyday irrespective of the user moving across different timezones. Set repeating with interval of one day will not deliver it at the correct time. How to approach this?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24196890/android-schedule-task-to-execute-at-specific-time-daily) is the closest I've got so far.

Code snippet:

```
private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
private PendingIntent alarmIntent;
...
alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

// Set the alarm to start at 20:00 PM
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 20);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);

// setRepeating() lets you specify a precise custom interval--in this case,
// 1 day
alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
```

Comment: Could you post your code? `will not deliver it the correct time` so when is the event delivered  now?

Comment: *This is the closest I've got so far.* that makes little sense. Please just share your own code

Comment: @shhp: I can set the initial time based on the calendar to 8 pm and then interval day is a constant 86400000. So it will send notification after 24 hours from current time but not adjust based on the current timezone(add or subtract difference).

Comment: @TimCastelijns: I have used the same code.

Comment: What code? There are more than 1 snippets of code in there

Comment: @TimCastelijns: Expounded the question for better clarity

Comment: @Srinivas Did you try my answer? It should work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To take `TimeZone`changes into consideration, you need to register a `TIMEZONE_CHANGED` broadcast receiver:

```
<receiver android:name=".TimeZoneBroadcastReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED " />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I would save the current `TimeZone` and then retrieve it when the next alarm occurs so we can double check if any changes took place, so the java code will be something like:

```
public class TimeZoneBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        String timeZoneOLD = pref.getString(PREF_TIMEZONE, null);
        String timeZoneNEW = TimeZone.getDefault().getID();   
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

        if (timeZoneOLD == null || TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZoneOLD).getOffset(now) != TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZoneNEW).getOffset(now)) {
                pref.edit().putString(PREF_TIMEZONE, timeZoneNEW).commit();
                // This means that the TimeZone has changed so we need to update the alarm
                // Set Alarm method goes HERE ...
    }

}
```

For more info about how to setup a recurring task using Alarm Manager, the following is a good tutorial:

- [Android Fundamentals: Scheduling Recurring Tasks](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-fundamentals-scheduling-recurring-tasks--mobile-5788)

Comment: This is probably useful, but it's only half of a solution. What to do in the `onReceive`?

Comment: Thanks mate! Edited my answer.

Comment: That doesn't change a whole lot. What is important is what exactly you do *inside* the `onReceive()` method. How do you reconfigure the alarmmanager so the timing is right?

Comment: aha, you mean if `Date` and `Time` changes?! I edited my answer once again.

Comment: Yep I mean that. However what are Provider and TimeManager classes?

Comment: @M-Y: I haven't tried yet. Have accepted the answer. Looks like this is the best solution possible.