# Scheduling background task for certain time every day in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, scheduled-tasks, alarmmanager, scheduledexecutorservice

I am doing an android app for a school project. I have made an AsyncTask within my main acticity that fetches data from the internet. I want this to be executed at 23:00 every day, and also when the user first installs and opens the app. I have searched online and tried ScheduledExecutorService, AlarmManager and TimerTask but I either run into trouble compiling my code or the application crashes on start. I am hoping for some help to get this working. Would really appreciate some concrete examples on how to schedule my AsyncTask.

I am currently running the AsyncTask when clicking on a button, but want to remove the button and run the task on a schedule.

Thank you in advance!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView ViewT;
private TextView ViewR;
private String deg;
private String rainD;

  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    ViewT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ViewT);
    ViewR = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ViewR);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new getData().execute();
            ViewR.setText(rainD);
            ViewT.setText(deg);
        }
    });


}
 public class getData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
//fetching data here....
}
}
}
```

Edit:
I tried this today and the application does not crash but nothing shows up on my textviews either.

```
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    final Runnable updateUI = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new getData().execute();
            ViewR.setText(rainD);
            ViewT.setText(deg);
        }
    };

    scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(updateUI, 5,
            60*60*24, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: possible to duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24196890/android-schedule-task-to-execute-at-specific-time-daily

Comment: @Hilda where is your AlarmManager and TimerTask post your code

Comment: @Ganesh I'm afraid I dont have the code anymore However tried again today and now it is simply not showing anything on the textviews but its not crashing either. Added my new code as an edit in my original post.