# Using an AlarmManager to run code every midnight in Android app

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, scheduled-tasks, alarmmanager

I saw this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/24198314/7767733 but could not get it working.

I have a function `refreshStuff()` which refresh the values of a Fragment. I call this function when the Fragment is being made, when the user updates the values, and during `onResume()`. I also want to force a refresh at midnight, which is relevant when the user is just looking at the screen and not doing anything.

But I am not sure how to set this up in my `MyFragment` class. I tried:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    ...
    private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
    private PendingIntent alarmIntent;
    private Context context;
    ...

    //in onCreate method
    context = getActivity();
    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

    //midnight I hope
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis()); //do I even need this?
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);

    alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
```

And if I understand the answer, I have to add this method somewhere:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   refreshStuff();
}
```

However I don't have `AlarmReceiver` anywhere and I don't know where to put `onReceive()` or what I have to define in the Manifest. I also don't know if I have to "turn it off" after I receive it? (do the "alarms" "stack" when they shouldn't?)

Otherwise is this the right way to do this so far?

Edit:

My attempt at implementing CommonsWare's answer:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements Runnable, SomeOtherListenersIUse, YetAnotherListenerEtc {

    private View viewForDisplayingTotals;

    //...rest of implementation omitted for brevity

    @Override
    public void run() {
        refreshValues();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        refreshValues();
        viewForDisplayingTotals.postDelayed(this, HelperMethods.getMillisecondsTillNextMidnight());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        viewForDisplayingTotals.removeCallbacks(this);
    }
}
```

My helper method:

```
public static long getMillisecondsTillNextMidnight() {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1); //add a day first
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0); //then set the other fields to 0
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    return c.getTimeInMillis() - System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

Comment: "I also want to force a refresh at midnight" -- why? If the screen is off at midnight, you should be called with `onResume()` when the screen turns on.

Comment: @CommonsWare if the user happens to be looking at the screen at midnight and not doing anything

Comment: Why is midnight special, then, as opposed to 12:05, or 1:37, or 13:37?

Comment: Because the fragment in question displays daily totals, and they should be resetting to 0 every day (specifically, the totals are computed by counting up items in a database where timestamp = sometime today, so at midnight, this procedure will return an empty set and therefore 0 total)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of all the `AlarmManager` stuff. That is for when you want to get control in the background at certain times, and in your case, this is only an issue when you are in the foreground.

Step #1: Add `implements Runnable` to your `MyFragment` definition

Step #2: That will require you to implement the `run()` method, and in there, call `refreshStuff()`

Step #3: In `onResume()` (or, better, `onStart()`), when you are calling `refreshStuff()`, also [call `postDelayed(this, ...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long)) on some handy `View`, where `...` is the number of milliseconds between now and the next midnight

Step #4: In `onPause()` (or, better, `onStop()`), call `removeCallbacks(this)` on that same `View`

This will cause your `run()` method to be called around midnight, where you will call `refreshStuff()`.

> //do I even need this?

Yes. Note, though, that your calculation is for the *past* midnight and ignores the seconds. `add()` a day and consider using `set()` to zero out the seconds.

Comment: Why is onStart better than onResume? Called both when the fragment is created *and* resumed or something like that?

Comment: I tried implementing your steps in my post. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: Wow, it worked, so I hope I got it right! I tried setting my emulator clock to 11:59, everything changed right on time to the right values. I presume this would not work if the user (for some reason) kept this fragment open for an entire day after it rolls past midnight the first time? (I'm less concerned about this because I can't imagine it ever happening in practice, but I am curious anyway)

Comment: @user7767902: "I presume this would not work if the user (for some reason) kept this fragment open for an entire day after it rolls past midnight the first time?" -- no, you would need to call `postDelayed()` again as part of your "hey, it's midnight!" processing. `postDelayed()` sets up a one-time trigger.

Comment: So I'd call view.postDelayed() at the end of the run() method as well?

Comment: @user7767902: Yes, that should be fine.