# Trigger Day Change In Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, date

How can I detect a day change in Kotlin, even when my app is not running or is off, and how can I run a specific command when the day changes? (**Im Using Android Studio**) **I'm Also Very New So take it easy on me lol** I want to change a text View When The Day Changes

I dont Know How To Do it

Comment: You could set up an alarm manager that triggers every day at midnight, however it's not that simple in android, you have to handle/consider reboots (to schedule the manager again), dooze mode, batery saving and other stuffs, but that should (if done correctly) work

Comment: Work manager is what you want to look at.

Comment: yes alarm manager and work manager too can solve the problem. But i think using broadcaste receiver is more suitable approach.

Comment: Apparently related? [Using an AlarmManager to run code every midnight in Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43023280/using-an-alarmmanager-to-run-code-every-midnight-in-android-app). I believe you can search and find even more.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a combination of BroadcastReceiver and DataStore (or the old SharedPreferences).

In your case, you can register DATE_CHANGED Receiver in manifest.

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver"            
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

When the day changes, the system will send a broadcast, which your app (MyReceiver class in this case) can receive and then perform the desired action, such as updating a textView.

Comment: So all I have to do is register it in the manifest and make a class with that name? Could You please go more into detail , thanks