# Scheduling task with repeating at specific time using Alarm Manager

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I've looked a various of an example of how to make a scheduling task using Alarm Manager; [source 1](https://www.sitepoint.com/scheduling-background-tasks-android/), [source 2](http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/06/scheduling-task-using-alarm-manager.html). But I'm a little bit confuse how to set the alarm at the specific time, because from what I understand its only have an interval of 15 minutes or a day from recurring. What I'm looking is I want it to recur at a specific time and repeating.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24196890/android-schedule-task-to-execute-at-specific-time-daily), but it's recurred 2 minutes late from the time that I've specified. Below is what my code looks.

**Activity**

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)c.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(c, AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(c, 0, intent, 0);

// Set the alarm to start at 3.46 PM
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 15);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 46);

// setRepeating() lets you specify a precise custom interval--in this case,
// 1 day
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, alarmIntent);
```

**BroadcastReceiver**

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   Toast.makeText(context, "triggered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Already set  `<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>` and  `<receiver android:name=".BroadCastRecevier"/>` in AndroidManifest.

Answer (score 1):

You can set exact time :

```
manager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC, startTime.getTimeInMillis(), operation);
```

And if that time has passed today, set for tomorrow

```
if (Calendar.getInstance().after(startTime)) {
     startTime.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Following permissions must be added first :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" ></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION" ></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" ></uses-permission>
```

Then:

```
 private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
    private PendingIntent alarmIntent;



    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

    // Set the alarm to start at 21:32 PM
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 21);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 32);

    // setRepeating() lets you specify a precise custom interval--in this case,
    // 1 day
    alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
    In this case, AlarmReceiver is the Broadcast Receiver and it already has a context, so you can directly set the ringer mode to silent from the Broadcast Receiver without starting an activity.

    @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);   
           am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
    }
```