# How to set the exact time to android job for a daily job at fixed time?

Tags: java, android, android-jobscheduler, android-job

I am trying to schedule the job which will run at 10 PM daily.

I tried to use the setExact method and provide the milliseconds by converting 22 hours to milliseconds and for testing I executed the app and changed the system time to 10 PM but the job did not execute.

I also tried to give coming time so converted 12:45 to milliseconds and given to setExact method. But that also did not work.

How can I set this and test?

FileTrackJob

```
class FileTrackJob extends Job {

        static final String TAG = "FileTracking";

        @NonNull
        @Override
        protected Result onRunJob(Params params) {

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getContext(), 0,
                    new Intent(getContext(), MainActivity.class), 0);

            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            Date currentLocalTime = cal.getTime();
            DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm a");
    // you can get seconds by adding  "...:ss" to it
            String localTime = date.format(currentLocalTime);

            Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getContext())
                    .setContentTitle("Android Job Demo")
                    .setContentText("Notification from Android Job Demo App. " + localTime)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setShowWhen(true)
                    .setColor(Color.RED)
                    .setLocalOnly(true)
                    .build();

            NotificationManagerCompat.from(getContext())
                    .notify(new Random().nextInt(), notification);


            return Result.SUCCESS;
        }

        static void scheduleNoti() {
            new JobRequest.Builder(TrackingJob.TAG)
                    //  .setPeriodic(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(15), TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(15))
                    .setExact(44820000)
                    .setUpdateCurrent(true)
                    .setPersisted(true)
                    .build()
                    .schedule();
        }
    }
```

MainActivity

```
FileTrackJob.scheduleNoti();
```

MainApp

```
public class MainApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        JobManager.create(this).addJobCreator(new DemoJobCreator());
    }
}
```

DemoJobCreator

```
class DemoJobCreator implements JobCreator {

    @Override
    public Job create(String tag) {
        switch (tag) {
            case TrackingJob.TAG:
                return new TrackingJob();

            case FileTrackJob.TAG:
                return new FileTrackJob();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Also I have scheduled one periodic job, this job is not working on some devices like red mi,on one samsung device its not repeated but on moto g4 plus it worked well.

```
class TrackingJob extends Job {

    static final String TAG = "tracking";

    @NonNull
    @Override
    protected Result onRunJob(Params params) {

        Intent pi = new Intent(getContext(), GetLocationService.class);
        getContext().startService(pi);


        return Result.SUCCESS;
    }

    static void schedulePeriodic() {
        new JobRequest.Builder(TrackingJob.TAG)
                .setPeriodic(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(15), TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(15))
                .setUpdateCurrent(true)
                .setPersisted(true)
                .build()
                .schedule();
    }
}
```

Can anyone help with this please? Thank you..

Comment: did u try for alarm manager ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24196890/android-schedule-task-to-execute-at-specific-time-daily?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Yes I tried with alarm manager. But it has limitations, if mobile gets switched off it dose not trigger the alarm also it dose not work with red mi , if the app is in ram then only alarm gets triggered. It dose not permit auto permissions in red mi OS. So I thought to switch to some other scheduler. @quicklearner

Comment: well u have to restart it when phone restarts its possible

Comment: but dose not work with red mi devices. this Android job also dose not work with red mi. Which scheduler to be used? Also I observed alarms are missed some times in other devices too. @quicklearner

Comment: well in redmi devices there is an option called Autostart , user has to select it manually for each app

Comment: is the problem due to app gets killed when user do that?

Comment: In red mi note 4 I was not getting the option to auto start the permissions. and in other devices may be when app is not in use the alarm dose not work sometimes.  @quicklearner

Comment: for redmi note 4 go to persmission then autostart select app

Comment: Would you like to have a quick check of my answer? @Sid

Answer (score 1):

You must use `DailyJob` instead of `Job` to do something at the specific time daily.

```
public static final class MyDailyJob extends DailyJob {

    public static final String TAG = "MyDailyJob";

    public static void schedule() {
        // schedule between 1 and 6 *PM*
        DailyJob.schedule(new JobRequest.Builder(TAG), TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(13), TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(18));
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    protected DailyJobResult onRunDailyJob(Params params) {
        return DailyJobResult.SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

Plus: If you want to set specific minutes and seconds, then use (assume between 15:48:05 and 17:42:09) :

```
    DailyJob.schedule(new JobRequest.Builder(TAG), TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(15)+TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(48)+TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(5), 
TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(17)+TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(42)+TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(9));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: is it possible to shedule in exact time eg.  23:59:59 ?

Comment: But would this run even when the app is not open? Also, the user has to open the app to schedule the job right? Is there a way to do it even when the user does not open the app? Say the user installs the app and never opens it but I want to send the user daily notifications.

Comment: @AnirudhGanesh This answer is very old, it used to work well back then. Also, this library is outdated now. We have work-manager now which executes Jobs with gurrantee*.

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics

Comment: It's not deprecated atleast!, I'm able to use it. I'm also using Work manager to build periodic requests and one time requests but then again, for running a work at an exact time, google still recommends alarm manager and jobs API. Funny thing about jobs Api is that, when the device goes into doze mode, I think it doesn't run! I tried it with different devices and for older API's it's working smoothly but in the newer API's have to resort to something else.

Comment: Yeah, google cares a lot about battery now. Even some 3rd party OEMs break normal features to squeeze the least amount of battery now. https://dontkillmyapp.com/